# Para que serve o "asp-fallback" no ASP.NET MVC, Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, razor, razor-pages

Eu vejo alguns arquivos como linhas semelhantes a esta:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
        asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
        asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
</script>
```

Pesquisei e encontrei em inglês (li utilizando o tradutor), e parece que ele chama o segundo arquivo se o primeiro falhar, porém eu não sei se é isso mesmo e nem para que serve o `asp-fallback-test` ou como eles realmente funcionam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando estamos desenvolvendo uma aplicação web uma das maiores preocupações é a o tempo de carregamento de nossa aplicação. Uma das técnicas de otimização usadas é usar os chamados CDN para as bibliotecas mais conhecidas.

Se o usuário já visitou um site que use o mesmo arquivo daquele CDN que você, este arquivo provavelmente esta em cache na maquina dele, o que elimina a necessidade de baixa-lo novamente. Isso é bom pro usuário que ganha em velocidade e pra você que diminui a carga no seu servidor.

Mas e se o CDN estiver fora do ar? Precisamos de uma segunda opção para baixar este arquivos. Os helpers de fallback do ASP.NET tornam mais fácil e legível fazer isso.

- `asp-fallback-src` é uma segunda opção para o src de um elemento html
- `asp-fallback-href` é uma segunda opção para o src de um elemento html
- `asp-fallback-test` é uma condição de verificação que podemos realizar para saber se o fallback será usado ou não.

Lembrando que os helpers de fallback podem ser usados para aplicar técnicas de Polyfill.

Existem alguma opções de taghelpers de fallback que você pode encontrar na [documentação oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers?view=aspnetcore-2.0)